# Permission denied when uploading file (Django, Apache2)

Tags: python, django, apache

I deployed a beta version of my django app to DigitalOcean and I am serving it using Apache2 for both python and static files.

Here is the issue, when I upload a file, it gives me the following error:

```
PermissionError at /admin/dashboard/marque/add/
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/verauto/site/public/media/marques'
```

Here is an excerpt of my settings.py file, as well as the sites-available configuration for apache2:

settings.py:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_ROOT = '/verauto/site/public/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

#STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'verautonoapi/static'),
#    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'boot'),
#)

#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'root')
STATIC_ROOT = '/verauto/site/public/static'
```

apache2 configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog /verauto/site/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /verauto/site/logs/access.log combined

        alias /static /verauto/site/public/static
        <Directory /verauto/site/public/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        alias /media /verauto/site/public/media
        <Directory /verauto/site/public/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /verauto/app/verauto-staging/verautonoapi/>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess verauto python-path=/verauto/app/verauto-staging/ python-home=/verauto/verenv
        WSGIProcessGroup verauto
        WSGIScriptAlias / /verauto/app/verauto-staging/verautonoapi/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see, in my attempts to solve the issue, I added the media directory in the apache2 configuration, I also did the following commands for chmod rights:

```
sudo groupadd XXXXXX
sudo adduser www-data XXXXXX
sudo chgrp -R XXXXXX /verauto/site/public/media/
sudo chmod -R 760 /verauto/site/public/media/
```

Comment: Which user owns the Django process?

Comment: chmod your media folder for django owner user